# while loop in arduino refuse to work (simple prog)

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Im writing a basic program that take 20 mms and control the on and off of the small light in the motherboard.
But the it always shows me an error
Can please someone help me fix it?

```
void setup() {

  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}


int cycle = 1; 
int time_t=20;
int time_on = 0;
int time_off= (time_t-time_on);
int big=0.05;
while (cycle<=100) {
  if (cycle%10==0) {
    time_on=time_t*big;
    time_off= time_t-time_on;
    big=big+0.05;
  }

  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   
  delay(time_on);              
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);   
  delay(time_off));    
 cycle++;  

}
```

Comment: PWM:13: error: expected unqualified-id before 'while'

Answer (score 3):

The arduino program syntax specifies that a program consists of two functions `setup()` and `loop()`. Hence the part to be repeated again and again must be written inside the loop function. So your code Will go inside a void function named `loop`. And it becomes :

```
void loop(){
  while (cycle<=100) {
    if (cycle%10==0) {
      time_on=time_t*big;
      time_off= time_t-time_on;
      big=big+0.05;
    }

  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   
  delay(time_on);              
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);   
  delay(time_off));    
  cycle++;  
}
```

Arduino reference : 
http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Loop

Answer (score 0):

i've not used this language yet but i see an issue with "int big=0.05;"  you're trying to assign a floating point value to an integer. should it be a double, float or similar data type?  and then inside the while loop you have

```
time_on=time_t * big;
```

once again you are trying to multiply an integer with a floating point value and assign that back to an integer. the result being the value of time_on will be some rounded version of time_t times big. the value of time_on will only change as the value of big approaches or equals 1. and the value of big will always equal 0. you need to change your big and time_on variables to floating point data types.